# Plotly Y ticks labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am trying to set custom labels on y axis in plotly.

That's how my layout looks like:

```
layout = dict(title = 'Tracer',
              dragmode = 'zoom',
               showlegend = True,             
              yaxis = dict(
                            tickvals = yTickValues,
                            ticktext = yTickNames, 
                            showticklabels = True,
                          ),
             )
```

The labels ['RwHandlerI2c', 'OrganizedTxSsp0', 'PIN_INT5_IRQn'] have the wrong formatting.

Experimentaly I have found that the problem in "RwHandlerI2c" label  is in the digit '2', label named 'RwHandlerIc' is shown properly. Am I losing something in formatting? And how to make the separate column for the labels, so they don't overlap the plot.

[image: Example plot]

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import datetime

yTickValues = list(range(8)) 
yTickNames = ['StartSendingSsp0', 'OrganizedTxSsp0', 'I2cRwHandler', 'GpsParser', 'SSP1_IRQn', 'USART0_IRQn', 'RTC_IRQn', 'I2C_IRQn']

xaxis = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686002), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686008), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686045), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686176), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686192), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686523), 
     datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 686530)]

yaxis = list(range(8))

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
x = xaxis,
y = yaxis,
mode = 'markers'
)

layout = dict(title = 'Tracer',
            yaxis = dict(
                        tickvals = yTickValues,
                        ticktext = yTickNames, 
                        showticklabels = True,
                        )
    )

data = [trace]

fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)

plot(fig, filename='example')
```

Comment: Can you add the your values as well? i.e. `yTickValues`, `yTickNames` and your `x` and `y` values.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters  I have added a sample code to my question with a buggy labels

Comment: The graph produced by your sample code looks OK for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nabom.png